# What windows server 2003 edition do I need for using Windows Media Services?

Tags: web, windows-server-2003

Just a quick question: What windows server 2003 edition do I need for using Windows Media Services (for streaming VOD wmv videos)? Can I just use Web edition, or must I use the 2003 standard edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/version.aspx) from Microsoft which has a table with which features are available with which version of the OS.